# How to get the return value of a method in ManagedBean in view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I m trying to get the return value of a method (submit) in ManagedBean in view. what i did so far is:

Managed Bean :

```
package net.javabeat.jsf;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean(name = "HelloBean", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

        private String nachName;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNachName() {
        return nachName;
    }

    public void setNachName(String nachName) {
        this.nachName = nachName;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
        public String submit(){
        return this.name+" "+this.nachName;
        }
}
```

and view:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />

        <h:form class="first" style="padding:25px; margin-right: 500px; overflow: auto;" >
         <b:panel look="primary" title="Suchen"  style="width: 450px; height:250px; background-color: white;">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="padding: 25px;">
         <h:outputText value="Name:"/>
        <b:inputText >
        </b:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="Nachname:"/>
        <b:inputText >
        </b:inputText>  
    </h:panelGrid>
             <b:commandButton id="suchen" type="button" action="#{hellobean.submit()}" value="suchen" styleClass="buttonSecond">  

    </b:commandButton>
             </b:panel>
</h:form>
          <h:outputText value="#{hellobean.submit()}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

But i cant manage to get the return value of the method inside of the
the last output text.
Probably i made somewhere a newbie mistake but i couldnt figure out where.. Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you need this? What is your actual usecase. Very likely this is an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: thats actually the case for me.. i just wanna get the return value of a managed bean method displayed on the page after button clicked

Comment: As you can see by the comment by BalusC, and mine, your 'usecase' is very uncommon. And normally the direct outcome/result of an action is a new page (or the same page). If you want to return values to the client there are different ways, like using plain ajax and update fields or [use some callback mechanism](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax). And if you already kind of mention the 'newbie' thing, don't answer _"that's actually the case for me"_  ;-)

Comment: FYI : `eager = true` is only applicable to application scoped JSF managed beans (thus, not other kind of beans like CDI beans).

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, you're trying to get the return value of a method, in the same page that executed the method? Huh?

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable in managed bean :

```
private String printOnXhtml;
```

Make its GETTERS AND SETTERS.

Then in your managed bean, change your function to -

```
public String submit(){
printOnXhtml = this.name+" "+this.nachName;
     }
```

And in your xhtml, change outputText to-

```
<h:outputText value="#{hellobean.printOnXhtml}" id="outputText"/>
```